# Generating a random number?

Tags: random, numbers

Hi i need a program that allows me to generate a random number but it needs to be a number with the same consecutive numbers like 222,5555,666,44,11.The program will keep generating until a number with the same consecutive numbers come up and stop. this is what i have so far. thanks for the help.

`int entierA8 = rnd.nextInt(10000 - 1) + 1;
        System.out.println("\n8.");
        do{
            entierA8 = rnd.nextInt(10000 - 1) + 1;
            System.out.println("Random number genrated: " + entierA8);
        }while();`

Comment: Perhaps instead generate a random number between 1 and 9, and then concatenate the number to itself a random number of times.